# Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused - Pocketsphinx on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pulseaudio

I'm quite new regarding Linux and I'm currently trying to implement the CMUSphinx tutorial adapted to french language (http://depado.markdownblog.com/2015-05-13-tutorial-on-pocketsphinx-with-python-3-4).

The specificity is that I'm working on bash on windows 10 (don't really know in fact if it's a point or not).

I installed SphinxBase and PocketSphinx, and then when I run "pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes", I have the following issue :
"Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused
FATAL: "continuous.c", line 245: Failed to open audio device".

I tried to seek on many links according to this issue, but I did not find any working answer.
I correctly installed pulseaudio, libpulse-dev and osspd but also not working.

Any clue? (As I'm not working with creator update, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04).

I edit to add some other information:
I also tried all what's dealing with stopping and restarting pulseaudio, but I have this issue with pulseaudio

E: [pulseaudio] inotify-wrapper.c: inotify_init1() failed: Fonction non implantée
E: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: inotify_init1() failed: Fonction non implantée
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-udev-detect" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Échec lors de l'initialisation du démon

When trying to kill pulseaudio : E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Impossible de tuer le démon : Aucun processus de ce type

When trying to start pulseaudio : E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Échec lors du démarrage du démon.

I tried to remove the ~/.config/pulse folder to create it again, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Trying pulseaudio in Windows is pretty bad idea, although it is claimed to work it does not work properly. Overall Windows development is not a good idea if you are not an expert.

In any case you need to install pulseaudio from [Windows port](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Ports/Windows/Support/), not from Ubuntu.

If you still want to create pocketsphinx application on Windows, you'd better try [prebuilt binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-5prealpha-win32.zip/download) or you can build them yourself in Visual Studio as an official [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx) suggest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as mentionned, I'm using bash for windows 10 which means that I only create (or test at least) pocketsphinx in a Ubuntu environment.I don't try to create my pocketsphinx app on windows. The only thing is that maybe windows is interferring with my bash app?

Comment: Install real Ubuntu in Virtualbox if you want to work that way, Ubuntu emulation in Windows is the worst way to deal with the problem.

Comment: I would have really appreciated to be able to work with this bash proposed within win10, but it's true that after installing a VB with Ubuntu and trying the same way, it's working fine. I will still let this open cause the issue is not solved and maybe someone has the answer. Thanks anyway.